# How to tell EntityFramework not to mess with given entity?

Tags: entity-framework, poco, dto

I'm looking for a way to indicate that a certain class is not to be used in the generation of the database (code-first web app) and not to be monitored for changes. In other words, I just want this specific class to be tottaly disconnected from any automatic persistence behavior (cause it will be used only as a DTO between View and Controller). Is it possible?

Comment: Why would it be incorporated in the EF model? That only happens if _you_ make it happen.

Comment: To include it in the database it either needs to be referenced by a DBSet in your context, or by something which is referenced in a DBset

Comment: @LukeMcGregor (and GertArnold) thanks for clarifying this to me... You're right, now I got it. No property of DbSet on the Context class, no control by EF. :) Thanks!

Comment: @LukeMcGregor, can you post it as an answer so i can accept it and close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework uses the DbContext class which you are using to detect the expected structure of your database.

There are 2 ways that EF will assume an entity exists in your database.

1. The entity is directly referenced by your DbContext, EG you have a `DbSet<TEntity>` (or `IDbSet<TEntity>`)
2. The entity is indirectly referenced from your DbContext, EG you have an entity referenced as above which has your entity as a property.

When an entity is referenced it will expect that a table with that entities schema will exist in the database. You can play around with how the actual expected schema will look (names, ignored properties, required/not required ect) by either decorating the entity with attributes or by using the modelbuilder. My personal preference is to use the modelbuilder, take a look at my article [here](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/07/entity-framework-navigation-property.html) for examples of using the model builder for navigation properties.

Comment: @MarceloMyara no problems :)